# "Root element is missing" error when import work item xml

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I have recently encountered a strange problem.

We using TFS 2017.3 and we have 2 app tiers with a load balancer.

I try to import work item XML with `witadmin importwitd`, when I try to import to the load balancer I got an error:

> Root element is missing

So I tried to import to the specific app tier URL, in one server I got the same error and in the second the import successful.

It occurs in any team project and in any work item type.

The XML is 100% correct (I success to import to the second server).

[image]

Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue fixed after restarting the TFS app tier server.

I don't know what was cause to the issue.